# Vim not indenting the c file like c++ file according to the specifiations mentioned in the vimrc file

Tags: vim

I am using the following vimrc file in my vim editor
https://gist.github.com/rocarvaj/2513367

I have changed the tabs and spaces section like this

```
" configure tabwidth and insert spaces instead of tabs
set tabstop=2        " tab width is 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=2     " indent also with 4 spaces
```

Now, I am using `gg=G` to indent my code and it is working for C++ file but not for C files. The C files get 4 space indentation instead of 2 as I have mentioned.

Comment: how does it recognize `cpp` files? I tried out and it indents with 2 space regardless of file named with `.c` or `.cpp` extension.. Also, suggest to remove the c++ and c tags, this is specific to vim only.. and migrate the question to http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your .vimrc, it ensures that indentation rules and plugins are loaded according to the detected filetype:

```
" Uncomment the following to have Vim load indentation rules and plugins
" according to the detected filetype.
if has("autocmd")
  filetype plugin indent on
endif
```

If you only want indentation rules according to the filetype, remove the "plugin" on the second last line of the snippet.